# Including jsp in a div asynchronously on same jsp when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, iframe

I am trying to implement a user account page. In the page when i click the links on the left side like 'search user' , 'prepare notes' etc. I want to include the related jsp page in the div on the right shown below.

[image]

I used an iframe in place of the div first but i could pass my session object attribute to the pages loaded in the iframe ,since iframe send separate http request.

I want to display the respective jsp pages using jsp:include in the right div instead of the iframe . The new target div will be in place same as iframe.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
 #dashboard-iframe{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">


//jquery function i tried   
(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchUser").click(function(){

        $("#dashboard-iframe").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchuser");

    });
});

//plain javascript
function searchClick(){
    document.getElementById('dashboard-iframe').innerHTML=
        "<jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchuser">";
}



</script>
</head>
<body onload="hidedisplay()">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="list-group pull-left">
                <a id="searchUser" onclick="searchClick()" href="#" class="list-group-item" target="dashboard-iframe">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Users
                </a>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/message_board" target="dashboard-iframe" class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> Message Board
                </a>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/prepare_notes" class="list-group-item" target="dashboard-iframe">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Prepare Notes
                </a>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/UploadYourFile" target="dashboard-iframe" class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Share File
                </a>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ComposeMessage" target="dashboard-iframe" class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Compose Message
                </a>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit-profile" target="dashboard-iframe" class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit Profile
                </a>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/connected-users" target="dashboard-iframe" class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> Connected Users
                </a>

            </div><!-- list-group end -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dashboard-iframe">
        <!-- Where i want to display the pages -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried some jquery as well as plain javascript but its not working. I needed the solution little early..sorry. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
function searchClick(){
    $('#dashboard-iframe').load('/searchuser');
}
```

.load() loads data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Comment: If you could please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I do not see any `iframe` tag in your code. The HTML should contain an `iframe` such as:

```
<div id="dashboard-iframe">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

And then your JS code should read:

```
$("#searchUser").click(function(){    
   $("#dashboard-iframe > iframe").attr("src", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchuser");    
});
```

Comment: sorry, but this is the version i tried ...i don't really want an iframe so i did'nt add one. I just want to include jsp page in div 'dashboard-iframe' asynchronously. so that i can work with session objects. since session objects cannot be passed to the iframe page